# Call rest api from android application using cordova

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I am creating a android application using cordova, I have index.Html and javascript, and I am trying to call javascript function from Html, call is not hitting javascript function. Is it any difference than web application. Do we need to include any libraries.
Second question is:- How to call rest api from javascript.

Any help or links to reference materials is appreciated.

```
        <div>

        <button onclick="printIframe()">Print</button>

    </div>


<script type="text/javascript">

    printIframe: function() {

    alert("in print i frame function");

      $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost:8178/,
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: 'application/json',
        success: function() {
            alert("Success!");
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log(textStatus + jqXHR.responseText);
        }
    });
```

Comment: have you included jquery library in your page ??

Comment: No I didn't, do I need to add, I am completely new. Can anyone help me on this

Comment: You need to give reference to jquery library because $.ajax method defined in jquery

Answer (score 2):

To make it work above code snippet

1.Give the reference to jquery library

2.Use your system ip address instead of **localhost** since mobile doesn't contain localhost

3.Define printIframe: function() as printIframe = function()

```
 <div>

        <button onclick="printIframe()">Print</button>

    </div>


<script type="text/javascript">

    printIframe = function() {

    alert("in print i frame function");

      $.ajax({
        url: "http://YourIpAddress:8178/,
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: 'application/json',
        success: function() {
            alert("Success!");
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log(textStatus + jqXHR.responseText);
        }
    });
```

Hope it will help you

Comment: Mention  var printIframe = function(){ //data }

Comment: @Naresh Kumar, yeah it is working now and am getting json object now

Answer (score 0):

Rename your method to

```
function functionname () {}
```

Then call it like this: `functionname()`

It will work you can't create method like the one you submitted in the question in JavaScript

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
    
        
     function  printIframe() {
        
        alert("in print i frame function");

          $.ajax({
            url: "http://localhost:8178/,
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: 'application/json',
            success: function() {
                alert("Success!");
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log(textStatus + jqXHR.responseText);
            }
        });

    </script>

Comment: Can you please use onClick="printIframe()" clicks c shall be capital

Answer (score 0):

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
          $("#boutonAlerte").click(function(){
            var fname = $("#fname").val();
            var lname = $("#lname").val();
            var password = $("#password").val();
            var email = $("#email").val();
            var dataString = 'fname='+ fname + '&lname='+ lname + '&password='+ password + '&email='+ email;
            $.ajax({
            url: "http://localhost/RestApi/test.php",
            type: 'POST',
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            success: function(result){
              alert('You have successfully registered');
              window.location = "dashboard.html";
            }
            });
          });
        });
```